# Min size subset of string with unique characters

Tags: c++, string, substring

Given a string find min non reapeating substring of that string.

Test1 : ababababababab
Output : ab

Test2: abcd
Output : abcd

Pls help how to do it.

Comment: I think say s = "abababab" string ns = (s + s).substr(1, 2*s.size() - 1); x = ns.find(s); return s.substr(0, x + 1);

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time, to fix mistakes, add clarification, etc rather than adding followup comments. Most importantly, **do not post entire blocks of code in the comments** -- it can't be read or understood easily. It needs to be [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the question itself.